# Accessing android activity from ASP.NET MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net-mvc

If I have an android application that opens a WebView activity for displaying an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, is there any way that I can access an activity or launch an intent from inside of the web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. You'll want [`WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). This will allow you to expose any methods of your Android app to javaScript, which in turn can interact with your web application.